# Hiding selected subcommands using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I am using argparse and have set-up subcommands to my program. I have created sub-parsers to define these sub-commands. I have some admin commands that shouldn't be shown to users in the help screen. I know we could hide arguments of a sub-command, but I don't know how we could hide few of the subcommands from showing up in the help list.

Here's my code snippet,

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='myProg',
                                    description=desc,
                                   formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='sub_parser_name')


myProg_query.add_subparser(subparsers)
myProg_update.add_subparser(subparsers)
myProg_configure.add_subparser(subparsers)
myProg_result.add_subparser(subparsers)
```

When I run the help command, I get this

```
%> myProg --help
usage: myProg [-h] 

positional arguments:
{query,update,configure,result}
query               query information
update              Update 
configure           Configure system
result              tabulate the result
```

From the help output, I would want to display only "query" and "result" to the user. I tried to use argparse.SUPPRESS in add_subparser method, but it would hide all the subcommands. Whatever I searched only talked about hiding individual arguments of each sub-command, but not about hiding sub-command. I might have to create a custom formatter method, but wanted to check if there were any other way to achieve this.

Comment: You can do that by overwriting some methods from argparse.ArgumentParser class, read the source code and check which method is doing that, may be either print_help(), print_usage(), format_help() etc. you can overwrite inside your class. or module, some methods name http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#printing-help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`metavar` might do the trick:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
sp = parser.add_subparsers(metavar='{cmd1,cmd2}')
sp1 = sp.add_parser('cmd1')
sp2 = sp.add_parser('cmd2')
sp3 = sp.add_parser('cmd3')
parser.parse_args()
```

With this `cmd3` does not appear in the usage or help.  But it does appear in the error message

> error: argument {cmd1,cmd2}: invalid choice: 'cmd' (choose from 'cmd1', 'cmd2', 'cmd3')

---

You may have already discovered this use of `help=SUPPRESS`. But it requires a custom usage (and possibly description) parameters:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='%(prog)s [-h] {cmd1,cmd2}')
sp = parser.add_subparsers(help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
sp1 = sp.add_parser('cmd1')
sp2 = sp.add_parser('cmd2')
sp3 = sp.add_parser('cmd3')
parser.parse_args()
```

To the main parser, subparsers look like `choices` of a positional argument.  As best I can tell there isn't a way of selectively suppressing `choices`.

---

With this level of question, examining the `argparse.py` code itself can be more help than the docs. In this case I looked at the code for `class _SubParsersAction(Action)`. That's doubly true if you want to customize the formatter.  The existing alternative formatters modify just one or two methods buried deep in the class.

---

This issue has been raised as a bug issue, http://bugs.python.org/issue22848.

There is a patch that would modify the choices display based on `help=SUPPRESS` for individual subparsers.  But I'm recommending the `metavar` solution, at least for now.  There are other proposed patches for dealing with `choices`.

Answer (score 10):

looks like I found a solution for this issue without any patches for argparse.
It's enough to modify 'metavar' and do not set 'help' for the certain subparser.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='commands', metavar='{command}')

command = subparsers.add_parser("command",
                                help='command help.',
                                description='command description.')
suppress_command = subparsers.add_parser("suppress_command",
                                         help=argparse.SUPPRESS,
                                         description='suppress command.')
hidden_command = subparsers.add_parser("hidden_command",
                                       description='Hidden command.')
```

This results in

```
[root@localhost ~]# parser -h
usage: parser [-h] {command} ...

optional arguments:
-h, --help        print help message and exit

commands:
{command}
    command           command help.
    suppress_command  ==SUPPRESS==

[root@localhost ~]# parser hidden_command -h
usage: parser hidden_command [-h]

Hidden command.

optional arguments:
-h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still puts `    suppress_command  ==SUPPRESS==` in the output

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer. For the hidden command appearing in error message, I have a dirty solution, tested in Python 3.7 (might require adaptation for higher versions).

Once `metavar` is set the `(choose from ...)` becomes redundant. To suppress it, this does the trick:

```py
import argparse

class ArgumentErrorPatch(argparse.ArgumentError):
  def __str__(self):
    msg = super().__str__()
    return (
      re.sub(r" \(choose from .*\)", "", super().__str__())
      if bool(re.match(r"argument \{.*\}", msg)) else msg
    )

argparse.ArgumentError = ArgumentErrorPatch
```

and

> error: argument {cmd1,cmd2}: invalid choice: 'cmd' (choose from 'cmd1', 'cmd2', 'cmd3')

becomes

> error: argument {cmd1,cmd2}: invalid choice: 'cmd'

that is, according to me, clear enough and more readable (especially if you have many commands). The `re.match` confirms that we are in a case where one chooses a command (note that this might be adapted as **there might be use cases where a relevant "choose from" is removed**).

Of course, this requires to set `metavar` for each subcommand (*e.g.*, for `subcmd` in `myapp cmd subcmd args`). Still in Python 3.7, this does the trick to fill `metavar` for a complete subparser (*i.e.*, whose other subparsers have been added) without having to detail commands manually:

```py
def _metavar(parser, hidden_cmds=set()):
  parser.metavar = (
    '{' + ','.join(
      cmd for cmd in parser._name_parser_map if not cmd in hidden_cmds
    ) + '}'
  )
```

### Full example

If you have `cmd1`, `cmd2`, `cmd3` and you want to hide `cmd3`:

```py
import argparse
import re

class ArgumentErrorPatch(argparse.ArgumentError):
  def __str__(self):
    msg = super().__str__()
    return (
      re.sub(r" \(choose from .*\)", "", super().__str__())
      if bool(re.match(r"argument \{.*\}", msg)) else msg
    )

argparse.ArgumentError = ArgumentErrorPatch

def _metavar(parser, hidden_cmds=set()):
  parser.metavar = (
    '{' + ','.join(
      cmd for cmd in parser._name_parser_map if not cmd in hidden_cmds
    ) + '}'
  )

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
sp = parser.add_subparsers()
sp1 = sp.add_parser("cmd1")
sp2 = sp.add_parser("cmd2")
sp3 = sp.add_parser("cmd3")
sp3.add_argument("-o", choices=["choice1", "choice2"])
_metavar(sp, hidden_cmds={"cmd3"})
parser.parse_args()

print("ok")
```

Giving `cmd3` results in:

> ok

while giving `cmd4` results in:

> usage: script.py [-h] {cmd1,cmd2} ...
>
> script.py: error: argument {cmd1,cmd2}: invalid choice: 'cmd4'

and the "choose from" is kept for an invalid `cmd3` option:

> usage: script.py cmd3 [-h] [-o {choice1,choice2}]
>
> script.py cmd3: error: argument -o: invalid choice: 'choice3' (choose from 'choice1', 'choice2')