# Argparse - Suppress argument list

Tags: python, argparse

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
commands = parser.add_subparsers(title='Available Commands')

cmd1_parser = commands.add_parser('setup1', help="Setup Device 1")
cmd1_parser.add_argument('-f', "--freq", help="Frequency in (Hz)",  metavar='\b', type=int, required=True)
cmd1_parser.add_argument('-p', "--power", help="Power level in (dB)", metavar='\b', type=int, required=True)
cmd1_parser.add_argument('-c', "--current", help="Current (mA)",  metavar='\b', type=int, required=True)

cmd2_parser = commands.add_parser('setup2', help="Setup Device 2")
cmd2_parser.add_argument('-l', "--length", help="Length in meters",  metavar='\b', type=int, required=True)
cmd2_parser.add_argument('-b', "--breadth", help="Breadth in meters", metavar='\b', type=int, required=True)
cmd2_parser.add_argument('-w', "--width", help="Width in meters",  metavar='\b', type=int, required=True)

parser.print_help()
cmd1_parser.print_help()
cmd2_parser.print_help()
```

Results in this help output:

```
usage: test2.py [-h] {setup1,setup2} ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit

Available Commands:
  {setup1,setup2}
    setup1         Setup Device 1
    setup2         Setup Device 2
usage: test2.py setup1 [-h] -f -p -c

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -f, --freq     Frequency in (Hz)
  -, --power    Power level in (dB)
  -c, --current  Current (mA)
usage: test2.py setup2 [-h] -l -b -w

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -l, --length   Length in meters
  -, --breadth  Breadth in meters
  -w, --width    Width in meters
```

Please help me in getting rid of line **{setup1,setup2}** after **Available Commands:** in help output.
Basically I would like to suppress this like as command list is already displayed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding selected subcommands using argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692395/hiding-selected-subcommands-using-argparse)

Comment: The best you can do without surgery to the `argparse` code is to play with the `commands.metavar`.  This will change the `usage` display as well, so you might need to use a custom 'usage' parameter.